# Scala List to Map with Next and Previous values

Tags: performance, scala, functional-programming

What would be the best way to transform:

```
val arr: List[String]
```

To:

```
val mapArr: List[Tuple[Int, String]]
```

Where:

```
each Tuple is:
  - String value is the an odd index element of the list
  - Int the size of the previous value.
```

Example:

```
val stringArr = List("a", "aaa", "bb", "abc")
val resultShouldBe = List((1, "aaa"), (2, "abc"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`IterableLike.grouped`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.IterableLike@grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) for that:

```
val result = stringArr
               .grouped(2)
               .collect { case List(toIndex, value) => (toIndex.length, value) }
               .toList
```

Which yields:

```
scala> val stringArr = List("a", "aaa", "bb", "abc")
stringArr: List[String] = List(a, aaa, bb, abc)

scala> stringArr.grouped(2).collect { case List(toIndex, value) => (toIndex.length, value) }.toList
res1: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,aaa), (2,abc))
```

Comment: thanks @yuval However, The current implementation produce a bug if the list is not even. If the list is odd we should basically skip the last element.

Comment: @ypriverol But if the list is odd, what do you pair the last element with?

Comment: I modified your solution to remove the last element if is an even list: `val result = if(stringArr.length  % 2 != 0) stringArr.dropRight(1).grouped(2).map { case List(toIndex, value) => (value, toIndex.length)}.toList else stringArr.grouped(2).map { case List(toIndex, value) => (value, toIndex.length)}.toList`

Comment: Why do you need  to `dropRight`? `collect` will skip any single element `List`.

Comment: I drop the last element for the even list. I changed the example to check for empty list: `val result = if(stringArr.length % 2 != 0 && stringArr.length > 2) stringArr.dropRight(1).grouped(2).map { case List(toIndex, value) => (value, toIndex.length)}.toList else stringArr.grouped(2).map { case List(toIndex, value) => (value, toIndex.length)}.toList

Comment: @ypriverol Your current code drops the last element for the *odd* list (`%2 != 0`). I still don't understand why you need that. If you have an odd list, `collect` will simply ignore the last element as is.

Comment: Because if I don;t do it is giving me an error and not ignoring it.

Comment: @ypriverol Are you sure you're using `collect` and not `map`? Look at my answer, I've modified it an hour ago.